# One of the map element causes SEPM0017 error

Tags: xquery, basex

I'm trying to run one of unchanged code example from book "XQuery: Search Across a Variety of XML Data 2nd Edition" from publisher O'Reilly Media.

```
(: XQuery by Priscilla Walmsley (c) 2016 Priscilla Walmsley:)
(:Example 13-4 Serialization parameters in a map :)
xquery version "3.1";
declare namespace prod = "http://datypic.com/prod"; 
let $map := map {
   "method": "xml",
   "version": "1.0",
   "indent": true(),
   "cdata-section-elements": (xs:QName("prod:desc"),xs:QName("prod:name")),
   "use-character-maps": map {
                           "«":"&lt;%",
                           "»":"&gt;%"
                         }
}
let $element := <prod:name>Fleece Pullover</prod:name>
return serialize($element,$map)
```

I'm using BaseX 9.3.2 to do this. But when I'm trying to run code, I get error:

```
Stopped at C:/Users/Arek/AppData/Local/Temp/example1304.xqy, 16/17:
[SEPM0017] item() expected, xs:QName+ found: (Q{http://datypic.com/prod}desc, Q{http://datypic.com/prod}name).
```

When i remove 9 line with *cdata-section-elements* element, code runs. Whether is it problem with XQuery implementation or with code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the 3.1 function spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-serialize clearly defines that `cdata-section-elements` map value as `xs:QName*`, i.e. as a sequence of `xs:QName`s so the example in the book is right.

http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Serialization gives an example `"cdata-section-elements": "div"` and documents "List of elements to be output as CDATA, separated by whitespaces" so they might have a known difference there, perhaps motivated that the first way allowed was a `cdata-section-elements` attribute listing QNames in the single attribute value of a serialization parameter node/document.

In the past, when I encountered such differences, I think they said that earlier versions of the spec and/or BaseX allowed the currently supported way and that implementing the spec would break backwards compatibility.

I guess you can ask on the BaseX mailing list or even raise an issue on GitHub